¿Como puedo hacer restricciones de usuarios con firebase para mi pagina web con html y js?
En mi pagina ya tengo el panel de administrador donde ya puede Ver,Editar,Eliminar y Regirtar (CRUD).
Pero necesito hacer otro panel para los usuarios donde se daran ciertos permisos para hacer sus tares.
Ejemplo:

Usuarios solo puedan ver.

Trabajadores que solo puedan ver,registrar y editar.

Los administradores puedan hacer todo.


Aclaro que mi forma de login es por medio de Authentication de firebase.
